# Vector returns negative size c++

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, tree, cout

For an exercize, I want to print out a tree data structure that is based on Node objects. This means, every object has a vector nodes that again holds other objects of type Node. But for some reason, when I let print out this->get_nr_children of the leaf nodes which basically just returns nodes.size(), I get completely random (negative) Integers where it should actually return 0. The even more interesting part: Every time I compile and execute, it prints out different Integers that alway are some low negative numbers. I do not have a clue what is happening!

Node.h

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    virtual ~Node();
    Node(string name = "");
    string get_name() const;
    void set_name(string& new_name);
    int get_nr_children() const;
    Node* get_child(int i) const;
    void add_child(Node child);
    void create_complete_tree(int nr_child_nodes, int tree_depth);
    void print();

private:
    string name;
    static int node_id;
    vector<Node> nodes = {};
};
```

Node.cpp

```
#include "node.h"
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

Node::Node(string name) {
    node_id++;
    nodes = {};
    if (name == "") {
        stringstream str_sm;
        str_sm << (node_id);
        string node_id_str = str_sm.str();
        this->name = "node_" + node_id_str;
    } else {
        this->name = name;
    }
}

Node::~Node() {
    nodes.clear();
    // node_id = 0;
}

int Node::node_id = 0;

string Node::get_name() const {
    return name;
}

void Node::set_name(string& new_name) {
    this->name = new_name;
}


int Node::get_nr_children() const {
    return nodes.size();
}

Node* Node::get_child(int i) const {
    if (i >= nodes.size()) {
        return NULL;
    }
    Node node = nodes[i];
    Node *ptrNode = &node;
    return ptrNode;
}

void Node::add_child(Node child) {
    nodes.push_back(child);
}

void Node::create_complete_tree(int nr_child_nodes, int tree_depth) {
    tree_depth--;
    if (tree_depth <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nr_child_nodes; i++) {
        Node* node = new Node();
        this->add_child(*node);
        node->create_complete_tree(nr_child_nodes, tree_depth);
    }
}

void Node::print() {
    cout << this->get_name() << "\n";
    cout << "I got this many children " << this->get_nr_children();
    for (int i = 0; i < this->get_nr_children(); i++) {
        cout << "\t";
        this->get_child(i)->print();
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "node.cpp"

using namespace std;

    int main() {
        Node* root = new Node("root");
        Node* left_child = new Node("left child");
        Node* right_child = new Node("right child");

        root->add_child(*left_child);
        root->add_child(*right_child);

        root->print();

        return 0;
    }
```

When I execute it I get:

> root I got this many children 2   left child I got this many children
>   -62802357     right child I got this many children -62802357
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Your problem is most likely that `get_nr_children` returns an `int` thus `nodes.size()` gets converted from `size_t` to `int` which then overflows.

Comment: This won't answer your question, but you should be aware that `add_child(*node);` puts a *copy* of `*node` in the children vector. Further changes (such as in `create_complete_tree`) to `note` will not be reflected in the copy you added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem stems from

```
this->get_child(i)->print();
```

`get_child` returns a pointer to a local object.  That object is destroyed when the function returns so the call to `print` on that returned `Node` is working with an already destroyed `Node`.

What you need to do is return a pointer directly to the vector element like

```
Node* Node::get_child(int i) /*const*/ { // cant be const for the return
    if (i >= nodes.size()) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return &nodes[i];
}
```

Comment: That is what I initially tried to do, but then I received this error:     
error: cannot initialize return object of type 'Node *' with an rvalue of type 'const std::__1::__vector_base<Node, std::__1::allocator<Node> >::value_type *' (aka 'const Node *')

Comment: @TheWill Oops.  I forgot the function is marked `const`.  You will either have to remove that, make the vector `mutable` or do a `const_cast` to remove the `const` of `nodes[i]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Node* Node::get_child(int i) const {
    if (i >= nodes.size()) {
        return NULL;
    }
    Node node = nodes[i];
    Node *ptrNode = &node;
    return ptrNode;
}
```

Above you return a pointer to destroyed local `Node node` after `get_child(i)` returned. Correct code is below, that returns a pointer to a child in the vector.

```
Node* Node::get_child(int i) const {
    if (i >= nodes.size()) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return &nodes[i];
}
```

`main` could be implemented much easier without pointers and memory leaks.

```
int main() {
    Node root("root");

    root.add_child(Node("left child"));
    root.add_child(Node("right child"));

    root.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the function `Node* Node::get_child(int i) const`. It returns a pointer to an object that is destroyed by the end of the function call.

```
Node* Node::get_child(int i) const {
    if (i >= nodes.size()) {
        return NULL;
    }
    Node node = nodes[i]; // <- node is a copy of nodes[i]
    Node *ptrNode = &node;
    return ptrNode;       // <- returns a pointer to node
}                         // <- local objects are destroyed, including node
```

You must return a pointer to the actual element from the vector.

```
Node* Node::get_child(int i) const {
    if (i >= nodes.size()) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return  &nodes[i]; // <- Returns the address of the actual node
}
```